# What admin template do you use with LARAVEL 5.4?

Tags: php, laravel

I am in new and cannot find the best laravel admin template for php 5.6 which is compatible with LARAVEL 5.4

Would you please let me know what you use to create the dashboard and if it has support for UI.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use AdminLTE best theme for Laravel.